# C# string comparison failure

Tags: c#

My application is failing on a string comparison. I have put in a breakpoint and then used the intermediate window of Visual Studio and done the following experiment

```
subject

"<#MethodResourceObjectives​>"

subject.Contains("<#Method")

true

subject.Contains("<#MethodResource")

true

subject.Contains("<#MethodResourceObjectives")

true

subject.Contains("<#MethodResourceObjectives>")

false
```

This would seem to be impossible, has anyone got a clue what could be happening?

Comment: Perhaps the ">" are different characters which have the same visual representation?

Comment: maybe he is lying to you!

Comment: @joe, For fix to your issue, you can change the value(constant value) to which the subject value is compared with as it's containing unprintable characters, as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 57):

It sounds like there may well be an unprintable character between the "s" and the ">".

I usually use something like this to show the true contents of a string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:x4}", (int) text[i]);
}
```

That's not as convenient from an immediate window, of course :(

In fact, just copying and pasting your text into my [Unicode Explorer](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Unicode#explorer) (at the bottom of the page), it looks like this is indeed the problem - you've got a [U+200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) (zero width space) before the `>`. You need to work out where that's coming from.

Comment: There is. I copied and pasted his string in to dotnetfiddle to check and there is a character before the > that shows up.

Comment: @leppie, why would `subject.Contains("<#MethodResourceObjectives>") == false` for any (printable/non-printable) symbol **after** `>` ?

Comment: @AndrewC: Yup, I've just found that too, and put it in the answer.

Comment: @Sinatr: Because the constant string could have the unprintable character at the end and the test will fail.

Comment: @leppie, oh, you mean unprintable char in `Contains` function call itself. But than it can be **anywhere** in last test, because it's unprintable =P

Comment: s>"-s​>" 
s%3E%22-s%u200B%3E%22

Answer (score 27):

Doing a copy/paste of the text, I can confirm the same behavior.

Output:

```
"<#MethodResourceObjectives>".ToCharArray()
{char[27]}
    [0]: 60 '<'
    [1]: 35 '#'
    [2]: 77 'M'
    [3]: 101 'e'
    [4]: 116 't'
    [5]: 104 'h'
    [6]: 111 'o'
    [7]: 100 'd'
    [8]: 82 'R'
    [9]: 101 'e'
    [10]: 115 's'
    [11]: 111 'o'
    [12]: 117 'u'
    [13]: 114 'r'
    [14]: 99 'c'
    [15]: 101 'e'
    [16]: 79 'O'
    [17]: 98 'b'
    [18]: 106 'j'
    [19]: 101 'e'
    [20]: 99 'c'
    [21]: 116 't'
    [22]: 105 'i'
    [23]: 118 'v'
    [24]: 101 'e'
    [25]: 115 's'
    [26]: 62 '>'
```

Then

```
subject.ToCharArray()
{char[28]}
    [0]: 60 '<'
    [1]: 35 '#'
    [2]: 77 'M'
    [3]: 101 'e'
    [4]: 116 't'
    [5]: 104 'h'
    [6]: 111 'o'
    [7]: 100 'd'
    [8]: 82 'R'
    [9]: 101 'e'
    [10]: 115 's'
    [11]: 111 'o'
    [12]: 117 'u'
    [13]: 114 'r'
    [14]: 99 'c'
    [15]: 101 'e'
    [16]: 79 'O'
    [17]: 98 'b'
    [18]: 106 'j'
    [19]: 101 'e'
    [20]: 99 'c'
    [21]: 116 't'
    [22]: 105 'i'
    [23]: 118 'v'
    [24]: 101 'e'
    [25]: 115 's'
    [26]: 8203 '​'  <--------- input string contains 'garbage'
    [27]: 62 '>'
```

Comment: I added this as a community wiki as Jon Skeet already pointed out the issue. Was too long for a comment.